# Why does days number count not work in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I tried and it is OK

```
postgres=# SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
       current_timestamp       
-------------------------------
 2020-05-22 09:31:19.492038+02
(1 row)
```

But

```
postgres=# SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE('2020-01-01'));
 date_part 
-----------
         1
(1 row)
```

I want to count days in this year.

```
PostgreSQL 10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

select extract(doy from current_date);
 date_part 
-----------
       143
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting a day part from an interval does not do what you think it does, e.g. the resulting interval could be `5 months 6 days` and then the extract would return `6`.

If you just want the number of days for the current date, use `doy`

```
select extract(doy from current_date);
```

which is a shortcut for

```
select current_date - date_trunc('year', current_date)::date
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6631597951ccf833b14542185301d7a2)

**Edit**

Your timestamp calculation doesn't include the full day of the last day, and - as explained - `extract(day from ..)` extract the day **part** of the interval not the length of the interval in days.

Additionally, `to_timestamp()` returns a `timestamp WITH time zone` which also takes into account that one of the days in your interval is shorter than 24 hours:

You can see this when looking at the result without using `extract`:

```
select to_timestamp('2020-05-22', 'yyyy-mm-dd') - to_timestamp('2020-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') as c1,
       to_timestamp('2020-05-22 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as c2
```

returns

```
c1                                               | c2                                                
-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------
0 years 0 mons 141 days 23 hours 0 mins 0.0 secs | 0 years 0 mons 142 days 22 hours 59 mins 59.0 secs
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out, why does my answer give -141?

Comment: Because the 22-MAY is the day number 141 of the current year and you subtracted days from the 01-JAN to 22-MAY instead of 22-MAY from 01-JAN.

Comment: But take a look at my edit, accepted solution returns 143!

Comment: OK. Day of the year is 143 and not 141. They are likely rounding issues because you cast to TIMESTAMP which adds hour, days, minutes, seconds, etc which is here not needed if you need only the number of days.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
postgres=# SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')-TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-05-22', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
 date_part 
-----------
      -141
(1 row)
```